# how to split .csv data in python into specific structure?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file contains the following:

```
X1, y1,50 
X1, y2,20
X1, y3,30 
X1, y4,40
X1, y1,70
X1, y2,40
X1, y3,60
X1, y4,80
X3, y1,100
X3, y2,200
X3, y3,300
X3, y4,400
X3, y1,500
X3, y2,600
X3, y3,700
X3, y4,800
X3, xx, d
```

How to create a list from the above data in the following structure:
`[[X1,[50,20,30,40],[-1],[70,40,60,80],[-1]],[X2,[100,200,300,400],[-1], [500,600,700,800],[+1]]]`

The first value store the information of sensor number Ex: `X1,X3,X2,…..` (no sequence)

Each sensor send 4 different variables and its value in 4 different lines(except one case :last case):`y1=50 y2=20,y3=30,y4=40`

The value -1/+1 depends on the next line followed the y4:

*Case 1:*

If the next line contain the same sensor number (ex:X1) and the variable y1 then -1

*Case 2:*

If the next line contain the different sensor number (ex:X2) and the variable y1 then -1

*Case 3:*

If the next line contain the same sensor number (ex:X1) and the variable xx then +1

Comment: You're likely to get more help if you show an attempt to code a solution for this. Then people will just be looking at your code and make some corrections.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to programming, so I had a go at this just to learn for myself. This is LIKELY not a very efficient solution, but hey - it's something :-)

```
import csv  # import csv-module


with open("foo.txt", "r") as csvfile:   # Open file as csvfile
    foo = csv.reader(csvfile)           # Read as comma-separeted file
    raw_data = []
    for row in foo:
        raw_data.append(row)

    def get_sensor_data(sensor_name):
        """This function iterates through raw_data looking for a unique sensor name.
        It makes and packs lists in lists as per your rules on StackOverflow
        ...and returns the correct format for the data of one sensor."""
        sensor_data = [sensor_name]
        sensor_data_block = []

        for line in raw_data:

            if line[1] == " xx":
                sensor_data_block.append([1])
            if line[0] == sensor_name and line[1] == " y4":
                sensor_data_block.append(line[2])
                sensor_data.append(sensor_data_block)
                sensor_data.append([-1])
                sensor_data_block = []
            if line[0] == sensor_name and line[1] != " xx" and line[1] != " y4":
                sensor_data_block.append(line[2])
        return sensor_data

    def make_data_object():
        """This function identifies unique sensor-names in the raw data.
        It uses those names to call the get_sensor_data-function.
        The lists returned from the call are stored in the data_object list. """
        sensor_list = []
        data_object = []

        for line in raw_data:
            # Identifying unique sensor names, and calling the get_sensor_data function to get its data
            try:
                sensor_list.index(line[0])
            except:
                sensor_list.append(line[0])


        for i in sensor_list:
            data = get_sensor_data(i)
            data_object.append(data)

        return data_object


    print(make_data_object())
```

Comment: Returns [['X1', ['50 ', '20', '30 ', '40'], [-1], ['70', '40', '60', '80'], [-1]], ['X3', ['100', '200', '300', '400'], [-1], ['500', '600', '700', '800'], [-1]]] using your data.  As you can see, it is not responding correctly to your rule about +1 vs -1, but you can figure that out for yourself.